# How to create Popup Menu in Context Menu?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to create a pop menu for context menu, so that when I long press the context menu, it shows another pop up menu.

This is the code I've written for context menu

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn)
    registerForContextMenu(button)
}

override fun onCreateContextMenu(menu: ContextMenu?, v: View?, menuInfo: ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo?) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo)
    menu?.setHeaderTitle("Choose one")
    menu?.add(0, v?.getId()!!, 0, "Upload")
    menu?.add(0, v?.getId()!!, 0, "Search")
    menu?.add(0, v?.getId()!!, 0, "Share")
}

override fun onContextItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java when i long press the button it shows context menu, then i select context menu it shows popup menu.

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
registerForContextMenu(button);

 @Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Upload");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Search");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Share");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Bookmark");
    }

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        try {
            showPopup(findViewById(item.getItemId()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

private void showPopup(View anchorView) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, anchorView);
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Selected Item: "
                        + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
        popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_example);
        popup.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add SubMenu objects to your menu with the [addSubMenu()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu#addSubMenu(java.lang.CharSequence)) method.
[Here's](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) the reference for creating menus if you want to go more into menu creating stuff.